# How to return a ajax error?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to show a ajax error after submitting a form. It ends now with 'die'
but what is the best way to handle this? Just write something in this php file in 'script' tags?

```
if($_POST['postForm'] == 'newsletter'){

    $newsletterSubscriber = new NewsletterSubscriber();
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('CMS_newsletters_id', 2);
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('created', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('firstName', $_POST['voornaam']);
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('lastName', $_POST['achternaam']);
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('companyName', $_POST['beddrijfsnaam']);
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('emailAddress', $_POST['email']);
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('subscribed', 1);
    $saved = $newsletterSubscriber->save();

    die('subscriber added');
}
```

I tried several solutions I found but I can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: `JSON` response would be one of the solutions, try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is create a array and place any parameters you want to pass back into that array, then use `json_encode()` to turn it into a json string that can be easily processed by javascript

```
if($_POST['postForm'] == 'newsletter'){

    $newsletterSubscriber = new NewsletterSubscriber();
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('CMS_newsletters_id', 2);
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('created', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('firstName', $_POST['voornaam']);
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('lastName', $_POST['achternaam']);
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('companyName', $_POST['beddrijfsnaam']);
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('emailAddress', $_POST['email']);
    $newsletterSubscriber->set('subscribed', 1);
    $saved = $newsletterSubscriber->save();

    $response = array('error_code'=>0, 
                      'message'=>'subscriber added'
                     );
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

The javascript woudl be something like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "connection.php",
    data: {param1: 'aaa'},
    dataType: JSON
})
.done( function(data){
    if(data.error_code == 0) {
       alert(data.message);
    }
});
```

Note when you use `dataType:JSON` the browser automatically converts the json string returned to a javascript object so you can address `data.error_code` and `data.message` in simple javascript object notation

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, if I have my php script in 'connection.php' the url in my ajax is connection.php? At this moment it still leads me to a blanco page.

Comment: Okay! Sorry, one last question: how can I prevent that after submitting the form it directs me to a blanco page?

Comment: Maybe you need to use `event.preventDefault();` as the first line of the javascript that contains your button click handler to stop the form submitting as well as running the javascript

Comment: can I just paste the javascript in my scripts.js? It now gives a error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: I cannot possibly know, as I cannot see what you have already and how you have added this code. Maybe you should ask another question about that. I will look out for it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I opened another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715715/how-to-send-a-form-with-php-ajax-without-opening-a-new-page-when-send

Answer (score 1):

You can do like:

```
if($saved) {
die('subscriber added');
} else {
echo "error";
}
```

and In ajax you can check:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "savedata.php",
    data: form,
    cache: false,
    success:  function(data){
        if(data == "error") {
           alert("Data has not been saved successfully. Please try again.");
           window.location.reload(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check [jQuery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)? this comes directly from their example.
It says that you can use the `.done()` `.fail` and `.always()` functions

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
  alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
  alert( "complete" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the best solution is to make you custom `json` and send it to ajax:

instead of `die` try:

```
$message = array('error'=>'subscriber added');
 echo json_encode($message);
```

and in you `ajax callback` do:

```
function(success) {
    if(success.error) {
        //do stuff
    }
//do stff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a json message followed by a error number:

```
if($saved) {
echo json_encode(array('message'=>'Successfully saved','erno'=>0));
} else {
echo json_encode(array('message'=>'Error on save','erno'=>1));
}
```

js:

```
success:function(data) {
  if(data.erno == 1) {
   alert(data.message)
   //do other stuf here
   } else {
    alert(data.message)//if save was successful 
   }
}
```